# How to open an Option[Map(A,B)] in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, for-comprehension, flatmap, scala-option

I've done enough Scala to know what ugly code looks like. Observe:

```
 val sm Option[Map[String,String]] = Some(Map("Foo" -> "won", "Bar" -> "too", "Baz" -> "tree"))
```

Expected output:

```
 : String = Foo=won,Bar=too,Baz=tree
```

Here's my Tyler Perry code directed by M. Knight Shama Llama Yama:

```
 val result = (
     for { 
         m <- sm.toSeq; 
         (k,v) <- m
     } yield s"$k=$v"
 ).mkString(",")
```

However this does not work when sm is None :-( . I get an error saying that Nothing has no "filter" method (it thinks we're filtering on line `(k,v) <- m`) Gracias!

Comment: Actual Error when sm is None: `error: value filter is not a member of Nothing
`

Comment: What is `Tyler Perry code directed by M. Knight Shama Llama Yama` ? And if that was meant to be funny... it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Embrace the fact that option is iterable

```
(for {
   map <- sm.iterator
   (k, v) <- map.iterator
  } yield s"$k=$v").mkString(",")

res1: String = "Foo=won,Bar=too,Baz=tree"
```

## None resistant

```
scala> val sm: Option[Map[String, String]] = None
sm: Option[Map[String, String]] = None

scala> (for {
   map <- sm.iterator
   (k, v) <- map.iterator
  } yield s"$k=$v").mkString(",")
res44: String = ""
```

Comment: good answer, but I think it's better you avoid "map" as name because  it may lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val sm: Option[Map[String,String]] = Some(Map("Foo" -> "won", "Bar" -> "too", "Baz" -> "tree"))
sm: Option[Map[String,String]] = Some(Map(Foo -> won, Bar -> too, Baz -> tree))

scala> val yourString = sm.getOrElse(Map[String, String]()).toList.map({
  case (key, value) => s"$key=$value"
}).mkString(", ")
```

Comment: This was my existing code before the my attempt at the for comprehension. Hated it! It's so ugly!